# Record and playback live stream video in android

Tags: android, video, rtsp

How can I record and stream a live video from an rtsp link and playback it later?

Comment: Have you tried anything Anu ?

Comment: yes..i tried using mediarecorder..but it will only record video using camera.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the framework directly allows you to do that. Install ffmpeg to do this if you want to do it.

Comment: And why the negative marks? May I know? It would be good if it is followed up explaining something like "This is the way to do this.." so that I and others who read the post can learn.